# Why does the singularity markup simply disappear from my .scss file?

Tags: singularitygs

I'm 3 days new to singularity and for the past 2 days have had the issue where only my singularity (`$grids` and `$gutters`) markup disappears from my .scss file.

I know that the markup has compiled because the grids and gutters are present and functional even though no longer present in the .scss.

The most bizarre (possibly telling) part to the story is that commented singularity markup has never disappeared.

Anyone else experience this?  Anyone have a solution?

osx 10.9.1/bbedit 10.5.7/compass (0.12.2)/sass (3.2.13)/singularitygs (1.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Neither among Sass, Compass and Singularity modifies your `.scss` sources.

It might be your source code editor, or some GUI Sass compiler, or a virus, or a glitch in the Matrix.

Get control over your computer.